# How to update height of all nodes in a binary tree with one function call?

Tags: python, binary-tree

I have a binary tree consisting of nodes of this class:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,key,parent=None,right=None,left=None):
        self.key = key
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
        self.parent = parent
        self.height = 0
```

An example of a tree construction could be:

```
a = Node(1)
a.left = Node(2,parent=a)
a.right = Node(5,parent=a)
a.right.right = Node(3,parent=a.right)
```

I want to write a function that updates the heights of all nodes in this tree.
I have found ways to get the height of one node. However, I want to update all heights at once.

How could I do this?

Comment: traverse the tree in pre order and set the level of each node to it's parent's level + 1 if there is a parent, else zero

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add this recursive method:

```
def syncheight(self):
    self.height = max(
        -1 if self.left is None else self.left.syncheight(), 
        -1 if self.right is None else self.right.syncheight()
    ) + 1
    return self.height
```

You would call it on the root as follows:

```
a.syncheight()
```

Note that I would call the class `Node` instead of `node`, and you have a different parameter name than what you use in the body of the constructor (`left`, `leftChild`)

#### Suggestion

I would not pass the `parent` to the constructor, as that should follow from the information passed as `left` and `right`. The latter should get their `parent` property updated to refer to the currently created node.

You can then also keep `height` updated as you go, by updating the heights of the ancestors of the newly created node:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, key, left=None, right=None):
        self.key = key
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
        self.parent = None
        if left:
            left.parent = self
        if right:
            right.parent = self
        self.height = -1
        self.bubbleheight()
    
    def bubbleheight(self):
        height = max(
            -1 if self.left is None else self.left.height,
            -1 if self.right is None else self.right.height
        ) + 1
        if height != self.height:
            self.height = height
            if self.parent is not None:
                self.parent.bubbleheight()

tree = Node(1,
            Node(2),
            Node(5,
                Node(3)
            )
        )

print(tree.height)  # 2
```